# How to say "and her" as in "Your Sister and her husband" in Japanese

Tags: grammar

I am stuck on a piece of grammar I do not know. I want to know how to say "Your sister and her husband"

I thought that if I write it like あなたの姉と主人 or あなたの姉さんと主人さん it might sound like "Your sister and your husband"

What is the grammatical construction to say "Your sister and her husband"

There must be a shorter way to say it than あなたの姉さんと姉さんの主人

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think あなたのお姉さん夫妻 or あなたのお姉さん夫婦 are natural and common.